# Expected length of a stochastic process

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes

I have this matrix:
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{7}{10} &  \frac{3}{10} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{5}{10} & \frac{4}{10} & \frac{1}{10} \\  0 & 0 & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}

I'm trying to determine the expected number of iterations required for something starting in the first state to end in the final state.

I assume this was called finding the expected value of a stochastic matrix but that hasn't yielded what I wanted on Google.

I've never studied stochastic processes before, so all guidance / help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice way of finding *mean time to absorption* straight from the transition matrix: see [Absorbing Markov chains](https://probabilitytopics.wordpress.com/2018/01/08/absorbing-markov-chains/) by Dan Ma. Let $Q$ be the part of your transition matrix without the absorbing states, that is
$$
Q=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{7}{10} &  \frac{3}{10} & 0  \\ 0 & \frac{5}{10} & \frac{4}{10} \\  0 & 0 & \frac{3}{5}\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $W=(I-Q)^{-1}=Q^0+Q^1+Q^2+\ldots$ is a matrix whose entry $W_{ij}$ is the mean time spent in state $j$ before absorption, if you start from state $i$. In your case you have $i=1$ and you want the mean total time spent in all states $j=1,2,3$ before absorption, so take
$$
m = \sum_{j=1}^3 W_{1j}.
$$
It should be $7 \frac{1}{3}$.

A cheap and simple numerical way (and good for double-checking) would be to start with the state vector $(1,0,0,0)$ and multiply repeatedly by your transition matrix. After each multiplication, record the probability of being in the absorbing state; continue until it practically reaches $1$. Now you have a (numerical) distribution of the absorption time, so you can calculate its mean.